# Why there is no compulsion that LineBorder is not just be created by BorderFactory?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am trying to learn design patterns from JDK. I was trying to understand Factory pattern through BorderFactory class. I found that i can create different Borders e.g. LineBorder without using factory too. So why is so..? If there is factory available then why they also open that one can also create object of LineBorder without using factory.Then what is the motive behind creating BorderFactory?

Comment: "THE" answer will be hard to identify, unless David Kloba (the initial author of this class) makes a clear statement here. My guess would be that few, "simple" Border classes (`LineBorder`, `EmptyBorder`...) are made `public` so that people may extend these classes easily - serving as some sort of "stub implementation". But beyond that, it's true that there's hardly a profound reason to make such a class public when it is available via a factory.

Comment: @Marco13, the [How To Use Borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) tutorial also implies something similar in `Creating Custom Borders`. *If BorderFactory doesn't offer you enough control over a border's form, then you might need to directly use the API in the border package — or even define your own border.*

Comment: I agree. Then the use of BorderFactory is not motivated. Whoever know about this factory will use it and other will just create border directly.

Answer (score 0):

The JRE has now almost two decades of history, most likely (I'll get to that) BorderFactory did not even *exist* in earlier releases. While BorderFactory helps avoiding creating tons of basically identical border objects, a new XXXBorder() was the only way to create such borders intially. For compatibility with old code the classes and constructors need to stay public.

Unfortunately BorderFactory has no "since" in its javadoc and I'm too lazy to dig out 1.0-1.2 docs to check what was introduced when. A few methods in Borderfactory have "since 1.7", so it underwent at least some evolution.